# How can I convert Ascii into binary length 7?

Tags: python

How can I convert Ascii into binary length 7 this is what i have so far:

```py
f = open("two_cities_ascii.txt")

lines = f.read()

byte_array = lines.encode()

binary_int = int.from_bytes(byte_array, "big")

binary_string = bin(binary_int)

print(binary_string)

f.close
```

Comment: What does the input file contain? What output do you expect/want?

Comment: A text file with only Ascii characters. The output should be a sequence of 0s and 1s.